# When (and how) can geodesic distance be computed?

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, computational-geometry, geodesic

Consider a manifold $M\subset\mathbb{R}^N$, and let $x,y\in M$ be on its boundary.

> I want to compute the [geodesic distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry) between $x$ and $y$ along $M$.

**For which manifolds $M$ can we actually perform this computation?** How are these computations performed (references are preferable)? I am interested in both closed-forms of the geodesic distance and geodesic distances which can be "reasonably estimated in a quick amount of time," whatever that means to you.

I imagine this is probably possible for any affine manifolds and the sphere. However I'm not sure how to compute the geodesic distance even for the sphere. Is this possible on, e.g., a torus? What about polyhedra?

EDIT: @DavidK's comment answers it for the sphere.

Comment: A geodesic on a sphere is a great circle. There are various formulas for it, but basically the path is a circle with center at the center of the sphere passing through the start and end points.

Comment: Thanks @DavidK! Any chance you've heard of this for other manifolds too?

Comment: You may be looking for this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/37651/46975 "Riemannian surfaces with an explicit distance function?"